# Nexus OSS 3.30.0-01 Java version doesnt pick up latest java version

Tags: java, nexus

Trying to upgrade java version to 11 from 1.8 but nexus starts back to nexus 1.8

logs from nexus where I enabled this parameter with java version 11

```
# Uncomment the following line to override the JVM search sequence
INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java
# Uncomment the following line to add additional VM parameters
# INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS=

Logs from java

  Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-12-09 15:05:55 EST; 5s ago
  Process: 231743 ExecStop=/opt/nexus-3.30.0-01/bin/nexus stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 231988 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nexus.service
           └─231988 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java -server -Dinstall4j.jvmDir=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0 -Dexe4j.moduleName=/opt/nexus-3.30.0-01/bin/nexus -XX:+UnlockDi...

Dec 09 15:05:55 devlnxnexus02 systemd[1]: Started nexus service.


There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
 + 2           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java)
   3           /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain what is going wrong ? what is your error ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nexus OSS 3 system requirements page](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/product-information/sonatype-nexus-repository-system-requirements#SonatypeNexusRepositorySystemRequirements-Java),
Nexus OSS 3 only supports Java 8 (including the most recent version, 3.51).
The distribution includes explicit checks to select only Java 8 runtimes.

The issue requesting Java 11 support is [NEXUS-19183](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-19183). The issue is opened since 4 years. Some users managed to run Nexus OSS 3 with Java 11 by manually editing various files (see Jira comments)

Answer (score 0):

I am using java 17 to build the service and making use nexus oss 3.30.0.1.
The angular package.json has below properties to pull a specic version of jar from nexus.
"verigon-sharedlib": "2.16.2712",
Irrespective of the fact hardcoded version given to pull jars from nexus its not doing so. But after some time interval ( around 120mins) , if we try to build the package again it picks up latest and mentioned version. So there is basically a dalay while it picks up mentioned/latest jar from nexus.